# Python set filemode in logging configuration file

Tags: python

I am trying to config the loggers in a text configuration file using Python. Here is partial content:

```
[logger_root]
handlers=result
level=NOTSET

[handler_result]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
backupCount=5
formatter=simple
level=DEBUG
args=('result_log.txt')
```

I would like to rewrite the log file every time I run the system. But not know how to set it in the file. I try this but fails:

```
args=('result_log.txt',filemode='w')
```

A lot of articles talk about how to set it from the Python code. But I would like to set it in the file. How to do it? Thanks.

=======================================

Edit: I can write some info into the log file 'result_log.txt' by:

```
result_logger = logging.getLogger('result')
result_logger.debug("info to write")
```

But I can only "append" to the file. I would like to rewrite the file every time i run.

Comment: what do you wanna write in `result_log.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of the two methods:-

1. Backup the old log file and create a new file using `RotatingFileHandler`
2. Replace the file itself (provided you don't need the old log anymore). You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296208/1322460) for the steps

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. But I would copy the log file to somewhere else after every run. So I don't mind rewriting the old log. I would like to be able to rewrite automatically.

Comment: then in that case u should be able to do it by removing the handler and reassigning it everytime you run the program. See the link I have given.

Comment: in the link you gave, i need to specify the file handler explicitly, which is not what i want. I want to just give the log file name in the conf file, not in any place of the Python code.

Comment: You can use the RotatingFileHandler, so that you dont have to move it everytime u execute the code. You can use the handler for infinite length file. You can also try to truncate the file when you are trying to open it, so as to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the logger module, would you be able to use the below instead?

```
open("result_log.txt", "w").write("result")
```

I understand this would be a workaround for now, until someone is able to answer this question better.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But logger has a lot of benefits, maybe you would like to check [Python logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you *can* set `filemode` to `w` from within your configuration file. You just need to remove the explicit argument naming, like so:

`args=('result_log.txt','w')`