# Use basicConfig to output to a new file?

Tags: python, logging

I want to change the logging target file on the fly in mode code. Consider this snippet:

```py
import logging
import pathlib

log = logging.getLogger()

logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.FileHandler("foo.log")])
log.error("foo")
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.FileHandler("bar.log")])
log.error("bar")

print("--foo.log--\n",pathlib.Path("foo.log").read_text())
print("--bar.log--\n",pathlib.Path("bar.log").read_text())
```

The output is

```
--foo.log--
 ERROR:root:foo
ERROR:root:bar
--bar.log--
```

As you understand, this is not at all what I expect. Why don't the logging go to the respective files? Why does it fail, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `basicConfig` (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) states that

> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured for it.

The second call to `basicConfig` simply does nothing in this case.

You would need to manually unregister the `FileHandler` and either call `basicConfig` or manually registering new handlers. See this question at SO, for example:

[Restart logging to a new file (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296130/restart-logging-to-a-new-file-python)